# Precise detection of collision between two graphical items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem

I have two graphics items, `RectItem` and `CurveItem`. I need to detect precisely the collision between these two items. I implemented for booth items the `shape()` method. I verify if collision is detected when I move one of the items from scene `self.collidingItems(self.rect_item, mode=Qt.IntersectsItemShape`.

I collide the items by moving them in the scene, but the collision is detected only on top part of the `CurveItem`. I don't understand where I made a mistake.

[image]

**Code:**

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.cyan))

    def shape(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(self.boundingRect())
        return path


class CurveItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = self._setupPath()

    def paint(self, painter, styles, widget=None):
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF()

    def shape(self):
        return self.path

    def _setupPath(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(0, 0)
        path.cubicTo(99, 0, 50, 50, 99, 99)
        path.cubicTo(0, 99, 50, 50, 0, 0)
        return path


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.curve_item = CurveItem()
        self.rect_item = RectItem(-50, -50, 25, 25)

        self.addItem(self.curve_item)
        self.addItem(self.rect_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        print(self.collidingItems(self.rect_item, mode=Qt.IntersectsItemShape))
        super().mouseMoveEvent(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you will not use the `boundingRect()` to detect the collision you must return a `QRect` that is the minimum size that covers the `shape`, for this we can use the `boundingRect()` method of `QPainterPath`, besides it is not necessary to overwrite the shape `QGraphicsRectItem`.

```
class RectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.cyan))

class CurveItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = self._setupPath()

    def paint(self, painter, styles, widget=None):
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.path.boundingRect()

    def shape(self):
        return self.path

    def _setupPath(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(0, 0)
        path.cubicTo(99, 0, 50, 50, 99, 99)
        path.cubicTo(0, 99, 50, 50, 0, 0)
        return path


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.curve_item = CurveItem()
        self.rect_item = RectItem(-50, -50, 25, 25)

        self.addItem(self.curve_item)
        self.addItem(self.rect_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        print(self.collidingItems(self.rect_item, mode=Qt.IntersectsItemShape))
        super().mouseMoveEvent(e)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.